# how to filter already selected option from select reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a mapped `Select` component that has a list of names. I need to filter out the name that has been already selected in one `Select` Component and not show in others. (i.e only show non-selected values in other `Select` Components).

I tried to store the selected name in a state and filter it out and map the names in the option. But that seems to limit only for 2 select i.e in select one I selected a name, and that name is successfully not shown in the second select. If I select a name in the second selection, the first selected value is available in the third one.

**Code:**

```
const App = () => {
  const names = ["jack", "lucy", "leo", "patrick", "joe", "rio"]; //got from api
  const dummyData = ["Select One", "Select Two", "Select Three", "Select Four"]; //got from api
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      {dummyData.map((data, index) => (
        <div style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <Popover
        trigger="click"
        content={
          <Select
            key={index}
            placeholder="Select"
            onChange={(value) => {
              setSelected(value);
            }}
            style={{
              width: 120
            }}
          >
            {names
              .filter((n) => !selected.includes(n))
              .map((name) => (
                <Option value={name}>{name}</Option>
              ))}
          </Select>
        }
      >
        Click {index}
      </Popover>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The above issue can be solved by storing the selected name in a list. But in that case, if I select a name from `select one` component and change the name to another, both the values are added to the list, which gets filtered in other components even though the name isn't selected.

Eg: If I select `"jack"` in the first `Select` it is added to the list, and if I change from `"jack"` to `"leo"`, leo is also added to the list, by this second `Select` component misses out both `"jack"` and `"leo"` instead of just `"leo"`.

Expected behavior:
If I select `"jack"` from first `Select` it should show in other `Select` components.

Note:
This `Select` is inside its own `Popover` component.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/three-ways-to-trigger-antd-4-21-6-forked-nxiph8?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store, the selected names in a list, just update the list accordingly in `onChange`, like this:

```
onChange={(value) => {
           const array = [...selected];
           array[index] = value;
           setSelected(array);
        }};
```

Check it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/three-ways-to-trigger-antd-4-21-6-forked-u6oo1s?file=/demo.js).